# Mysql byte length

Tags: mysql

ive came across a [website](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysqls-character-sets-and-collations-demystified) who state that the following:

> Ex:  CountryCode CHAR(3) CHARSET utf8
>
> We are asking for a column with 3 characters exactly. The required storage for this column
> will be such that any 3-letter name must fit in. This means (3 characters) times (3 bytes
> per character) = 9 bytes of storage. So CHAR and utf8 together may be less than ideal.
> VARCHAR behaves better: it only requires as many bytes per character as described above. So
> the text "abc" will only require 3 bytes

Do i need for the text 'abc'(with utf8 and char(3)) 3 bytes or 9 bytes?!
Thanks

Comment: There is information @MySQL about this question I think may help "  For example, MySQL must reserve 30 bytes for a CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 column. ": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html

Comment: Thanks, Emre. Usefull ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's internal structure places CHAR fields directly within the table structure, e.g. A simple table like:

```
create table foo (
   id int
   name char(3)
);
```

would produce an on-disk record that looks like

```
xxxxccccccccc
^^^^-- 4 bytes of int storage space
    ^^^^^^^^^ 9 bytes of utf-8 char space
```

Since MySQL has no way of knowing in advance what kind of text you'll be storing in that char field, it **HAS** to assume worst-case, and allocates as much space as 3 chars of 'absolutely the longest possible' utf-8 text might take. If it didn't, then an overly long string would overflow the on-disk storage and start scribbling on an adjacent record.

varchar, on the other hand, only has a small 'stub' data section in the table's raw data, and the varchar's contents are stored elsewhere. That means that your varchar(3) will always occupy the same amount of table-space storage, no matter WHAT kind of character set you're using.

Comment: What you wrote about `CHAR` is entirely correct. However, I believe `VARCHAR` columns data *are* stored in-line (as opposed to `TEXT` columns). I'm still looking for hard evidence though.

Comment: [Found it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html): "The effective maximum number of bytes that can be stored in a VARCHAR or VARBINARY column is subject to the maximum row size of 65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns." (but +1 nonetheless)